# Typescript deserializing json into collection with multiple types

Tags: json, serialization, typescript

I'm using typescript for a project and need to serialize a collection to json, save it to a file and later deserialize that file into a similar collection. The collection looks something like:

```
elements: Array<tool>
```

and my tool interface looks like:

```
export interface tool {
    name: string;
    draw(context:any);
}
```

and a tool implementation would look like:

```
export class textTool implements tool {
    name: string;
    fontSize:number;
    fontType:string;
    draw(context:any){
        // draws the control...
    }
}
```

I have few implementations of tool interface: textTool, imageTool and rectangleTool. The problem I need to solve is that when I deserialize the file content into a collection of tool I get just a regular object and not an instance of textTool for example.

I'm using `JSON.stringify(elements)` to create a json and `JSON.parse(jsonText)` to deserialize.

I understand that the parser has no way to know which type it should create an instance of given the json text has no information about it. I thought of adding a field or something to identify which class instance I need and manually 'new' that class. Any options where I don't need to manually parse the json to collection of tool (with proper types)?

Comment: There are plenty of alternatives: You can save different types to different files, or to one file but with different "sections" each for each type. You can also wrap each of your objects like: `{ "type": "textTool", "object": { ... } }`

Comment: @NitzanTomer I agree that it will probably work, I wanted to double check whether there was something else or I was missing something.

Comment: "Better" is not an objective criteria. There *might* be a way to make it more objective by being more specific in what you mean by "better", but as it is this question invites opinions rather than facts.

Comment: You are aware though that using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` won't allow you to include functions right? As your interface does include a `draw` function.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan. Thanks, I changed the question to be more objective.

Comment: @NitzanTomer yes I know about that. That's why I would like to be able to parse back to a specific type of tool...

Comment: @LPains Do specific implementations have any additional persisted properties besides those defined in interface?

Comment: @AlekseyL. yes they do. I edited the post with an example of tool implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said you can add a field `type`, create a mapping between type-string to implementation-class and then conversion code will be pretty straight forward:

```
export interface tool {
    type: string;
    name: string;
    draw(context:any): void;
}

class textTool implements tool {
    type:string = 'textTool';
    name:string;
    fontSize:number;
    fontType:string;

    draw(context:any):void {
    }
}

const typeMapping:any = {
    'textTool' : textTool
    //all other types
};
let json = '[{"type":"textTool", "name": "someName", "fontSize": 11}]';
let elements: Array<tool> = JSON.parse(json).map((i:any) => {
    let target:any = new typeMapping[i.type];
    for (const key in i) {
        target[key] = i[key];
    }
    return target;
});
```

* Cloning code is very simplistic, but it is good enough for plain objects.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this on my environment.

Comment: is this (2019) still the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

for plain objects try it:

```
function deserialize<T>(json): T[] {
    let collection: T[] = [];
    json.map((item: T) => {
        collection.push(item);
    });
    return collection;
}
```

and call it:

```
let tools: tool[] = deserialize<textTool>(json);
```