# How to handle duck-typed union types to TypeScript interfaces?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and still trying to get the hang of things.

I have an array of events that form a timeline. They look something like this:

```
const timeline = [{
  type: 'payment',
  amount: '12.23 USD',
  when: '<iso timestamp>'
},{
  type: 'payment',
  amount: '12.23 USD',
  when: '<iso timestamp>'
},{
  type: 'refunded',
  amount: '2.00 USD',
  when: '<iso timestamp>'
},{
  type: 'payment',
  amount: '12.23 USD',
  when: '<iso timestamp>'
},{
  type: 'delinquent',
  when: '<iso timestamp>'
}]
```

So I've gone and defined an `IEvent` as a union type:

```
interface IPaymentEvent {
  amount: string,
  when: string
}

interface IRefundedEvent {
  amount: string,
  when: string
}

interface IDelinquentEvent {
  when: string
}

type IEvent = IPaymentEvent | IRefundedEvent | IDelinquentEvent
```

The problem is that I'm confused how to use this type information in my code. How do I convert that timeline into the actual types that I just defined? And how to I deconstruct the union type when I iterate over the array?

My attempt at it looks like this:

```
class PaymentEvent implements IPaymentEvent {}
class RefundedEvent implements IRefundedEvent {}
class DelinquentEvent implements IDelinquentEvent {}

const duckTypeMap = {
  payment: PaymentEvent,
  refunded: RefundedEvent,
  delinquent: DelinquentEvent
}

const typedTimeline = timeline.map(x => {
  return duckTypeMap[x.type](x)
})

console.log(typedTimeline)
```

[But that's not quite working](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20timeline%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%09type%3A%20'payment'%2C%0D%0A%09amount%3A%20'12.23%20USD'%2C%0D%0A%09when%3A%20'%3Ciso%20timestamp%3E'%0D%0A%7D%2C%7B%0D%0A%09type%3A%20'payment'%2C%0D%0A%09amount%3A%20'12.23%20USD'%2C%0D%0A%09when%3A%20'%3Ciso%20timestamp%3E'%0D%0A%7D%2C%7B%0D%0A%09type%3A%20'refunded'%2C%0D%0A%09amount%3A%20'2.00%20USD'%2C%0D%0A%09when%3A%20'%3Ciso%20timestamp%3E'%0D%0A%7D%2C%7B%0D%0A%09type%3A%20'payment'%2C%0D%0A%09amount%3A%20'12.23%20USD'%2C%0D%0A%09when%3A%20'%3Ciso%20timestamp%3E'%0D%0A%7D%2C%7B%0D%0A%09type%3A%20'delinquent'%2C%0D%0A%09when%3A%20'%3Ciso%20timestamp%3E'%0D%0A%7D%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IPaymentEvent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20amount%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20when%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IRefundedEvent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20amount%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20when%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IDelinquentEvent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20when%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20IEvent%20%3D%20IPaymentEvent%20%7C%20IRefundedEvent%20%7C%20IDelinquentEvent%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20PaymentEvent%20implements%20IPaymentEvent%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20RefundedEvent%20implements%20IRefundedEvent%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20DelinquentEvent%20implements%20IDelinquentEvent%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20duckTypeMap%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20payment%3A%20PaymentEvent%2C%0D%0A%20%20refunded%3A%20RefundedEvent%2C%0D%0A%20%20delinquent%3A%20DelinquentEvent%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20typedTimeline%20%3D%20timeline.map(x%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20duckTypeMap%5Bx.type%5D(x)%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(typedTimeline)%0D%0A%0D%0A.)

I get the feeling that there has to be a common practice here. I'm also interested if there are two ways to do this, (1) with es6 classes and (2) without es6 classes. For the latter, it seems like the type system ought to be able to help out if we tell it how duck type the JSON.

Comment: Consider using strings as types, as in `interface IRefundedEvent { type: "refunded"; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Few things to fix:

1. In order to create instance of type you should use `new` keyword - `new duckTypeMap[x.type];`
2. In order to initialize this instance's fields you should create copy constructor or just map json object (manually or with some library). Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100853/typescript-deserializing-json-into-collection-with-multiple-types/38104840#38104840) answer for example.
3. If your class implements the interface it should declare members of this interface. Also not sure what you gain from using `union` type. In order to have polymorphic array you could just define single interface `IEvent` with `when` property and implement it in all classes.

Something like this:

```
interface IEvent {
    when: string
}

class PaymentEvent implements IEvent {
    public amount:string;
    public when:string;
}

const typedTimeline:IEvent[] = timeline.map(x => {
    let target = new duckTypeMap[x.type];
    for (const key in x) {
        target[key] = x[key];
    }
    return target;
});
```

To determine item type when you iterate over the "typed" array you can use `instanceof` operator:

```
if(item instanceof RefundedEvent)
```

Comment: (2) bummer -- is there any way to automatically generate a class that represents this type? (3) the point of the union type is because events may have different fields entirely. And I want to be able to iterate through, check the instance, and render events differently.

Comment: wait, can I do something like this? `type paymentEvent = {when: string, type: string, amount: string}`

Comment: Automatically generate from what? Json? (3) - array of `any` objects can be used if you're not doing anything common with them. And yes, you can define inline types as far as I know