# How to convert a given xml to an instance of a defined Typescript class?

Tags: json, xml, node.js, typescript, xsd

## Hello,

In my application im going to use [cxsd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cxsd) module in order to generate a Typescript class from a given xsd. The application is fed by xml inputs that I then do some logics on, converting the input to a known object by another web service and send it to the web service.

---

For example, recieving a `DogXML` input -> converting to `OutputDog` -> sending to the webservice that expects the `OutputDog`

---

I couldnt find converting the input xml to the output object so trivial.
Writing an application with Typescript made it clear for me that i need to **somehow** parse the xml input to the generated Typescript classes by the `cxsd`. *my question is how?*

---

**How do you parse a given xml to an instance of an existing Class?**

---

What i want to achieve is :

- Recieving a `DogXML`
- Creating a `Dog` instance of this xml
- Do logic and convert it to `OutputDog`
- Send the `OutputDog` to the web service

---

*Currently i am using [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) module to convert the input xml into a JSON and work on it, the problem is that the output of the parsing to JSON is `any` and I cant access the properties of `Dog` since it doesn't know `Dog`'s properties. This is why I need to create an instance of `Dog` from the given XML*

---

Thanks in advance, hopefully i made myself clear!

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100853/typescript-deserializing-json-into-collection-with-multiple-types/38104840#38104840) might be helpful (explained how to convert json to instance of type)

Comment: Did you have some Code?

Comment: @Magu i dont have some code that i can upload here.

Comment: @AlekseyL.converting from json to an instace is something im able to achieve with TypedJson package. but i recieve alot of input, and would like to do it right away from xml to an instance

Comment: Would realy appreciate help, still have the problem..