# Typescript: How to deserialize JSON object with private variables?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, local-storage

I have the following typescript model object `user`

```
export class User {

constructor(
    private _name: string,
    private _email: string
)  {}


public get name():string {
    return this._name;
}

public set name(value:string) {
    this._name = value;
}

get email():string {
    return this._email;
}

set email(value:string) {
    this._email = value;
}

}
```

I store the object via this code:

```
let user = new User('myName', 'myEmail');
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
```

If I look into the local storage there is the following string:

```
{"_name":"myName","_email":"myEmail"}
```

How do I get the user object again?

```
let user: User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
console.log(user.name); // logs undefined. Should log 'myName'
console.log(user._name); // this logs 'myName'. But according to the typescript documentation this should NOT work!
```

I guess this has something to to with the underscores the object is stored with.
How can I receive the object correctly?

Comment: `JSON.parse` returns plain js object (not of type `User`). You should create `User` instance manually and initialize it. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100853/typescript-deserializing-json-into-collection-with-multiple-types/38104840#38104840) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement some serialize and deserialize methods in your model.

```
class User {
    static public deserialize(serialized) {
        const {name, email} = JSON.parse(serialized);
        return new User(name, email);
    }    

    constructor(
        private _name: string,
        private _email: string
    )  {}


    public get name():string {
        return this._name;
    }

    public set name(value:string) {
        this._name = value;
    }

    get email():string {
        return this._email;
    }

    set email(value:string) {
        this._email = value;
    }

    public serialize() {
        return JSON.stringify({name: this.name, email: this.email});
    }

}

let user = new User('myName', 'myEmail');
localStorage.setItem('user', user.serialize());

let user1: User = User.deserialize(localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [answer to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59175926/11584033), I came up with this solution based on `JSON.parse()`'s [reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) parameter:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(json, function (key, value) {
    if (key.startsWith('_')) {
        this[key.slice(1)] = value
        return
    }
    return value
})
```

This works the other way around too with `JSON.stringify()`'s [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) parameter.

Note that the callback won't work with an arrow function since they don't have their own binding to `this`